# Vertical line reducing width at the both Ends

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a requirement to draw a vertical line shown in Image attached. it has a width of say (1 px) Equal width in the middle but at the Dead ends it shoul look like getting disappeared. I tried with line and border but it does not look like getting disappeared at the dead ends.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use a `Rectangle` with a `LinearGradient` as its `Fill` brush.

Comment: Ah sorry man I think you beat me by some seconds, how about you just C/P my example into yours and I'll del out since you beat me?

Comment: @ChrisW.: T'is fine :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this;

```
<Rectangle Width="1">
   <Rectangle.Fill>
      <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
         <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0.75"/>
         <GradientStop Offset="1"/>
         <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0.25"/>
         <GradientStop Offset="0"/>
      </LinearGradientBrush>
   </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

[image]